# How to install vlc package statically with all dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, vlc, configure, libvlc

I want to install Libvlc statically with

```
./configure --enable-static --prefix=path_to_libs/libs/vlc-3.0.3
```

but every time I run the command there pops up a error because a dependency is missing. I want to compile my c program locally so all libraries aand dependencies should be installed locally. First I downloaded and installed a couple of them (libxcb for example) but to every ./configure comand there appears a new missing dependency. The dependencies require other dependencies so there is kind of a  loop.

Example:

vlc-3.0-3 requires xcb

xcb requires xcb-proto

xcb requires xau

xcb requires pthread-stubs

Is there a method to automatize the entire process?

Comment: install `libvlc-dev` and `vlc` from official package managers

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer! 
 I think I already did this, could you send me please the link you're talking about? If I install libvlc-dev STATICALLY the dependencies will be still discarded / auto-configured?

Comment: https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/extras/package/snap/snapcraft.yaml. It's not clear from your Q if you're trying to build libvlc or use it btw.

Comment: Thank you. I want to install libvlc statically in a folder and use the lib in order to writr a cpp program which compiles statically.